# comparing times with datetime

Tags: python, datetime

I'm new to python, and I'm trying to use a time in a while statement.

```
while hours_left is greater than 0:00
{
    do some stuff
    decrement hours_left
}
```

is what I'm trying to achieve.

however I can't just say `hours_left > 0` because it's an int.

any ideas how I can type `0:00` as datetime?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want a [`timedelta`](http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#timedelta-objects) object.

```
import datetime
current_time = datetime.datetime(2011,12,12,12,0,0) # High Noon!
end_time = datetime.datetime(2011,12,25,0,0,0)      # Santa?
while end_time-current_time > datetime.timedelta(0):
    do_stuff()
    current_time = current_time - datetime.timedelta(hours=1)
```

Comment: I've been using timedelta already, the part I missed is, and if I understand it correctly, `timedelta(0)` will always = 0 right?

Comment: I get a TypeError of unorderable types, datetime.datetime() > datetime.timedelta()

Comment: You can't compare a date with a date difference. Think for a moment about what you're doing: You're asking something like "Is *November 3rd, half past twelve* bigger than *one hour*?". That can't work. You need (as shown in my sample) a current date (real or fabricated) and a defined end date, then calculate the difference (delta!) and compare *that* to whatever timespan you want (in this case `timedelta(0)`).

Answer (score 0):

Sure, take a current datetime object, add the hours left to it, and then compare the current object to the new one with the hours left.  If the current one is less than the new one then you still have hours left.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your saying I should make a new call for the current time, and use that to compare. The problem is, this is for a calendar application. The time is abstract, it's not actual. Which means I can't just get the current time.

Comment: It can be an abstract time, I assume that you are managing the time still somehow.  If it were stationary then even with .0001 hours left it would still never run out of time.